# Why is it wrong to say that $1/x$ is continuous everywhere but at $0$

Tags: analysis

Why is it wrong to say that $1/x$ is not continuous at $0$. Because $1/0$ is not defined??

Comment: It is also true that the singularity at $x=0$ is not a removable singularity - i.e. there is no value which can be defined for $x=0$ (where the function is undefined) which would make the function continuous.

Comment: Doesn't sound *wrong* (as in false) to me, either the version in the title or the version in the post.

Comment: Its from a book an anecdote that there are school teachers who say that $1/x$ is discontinous at $x=0$, and this is wrong. And that the correct formulation is $f(x)=1/x$ is continuous $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\} $

Comment: @AndréNicolas:  I guess "continuous everywhere but at $0$" implyies that $0$ is in the domain of the function.  I took it as VVV said in the last comment.

Comment: @VVV: Again, please do not "sign your posts". Also, at least to me, "Tell me. Please." just sounds wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I note that in one of the comments, VVV writes:

> Its from a book an anecdote that there are school teachers who say that $1/x$ is discontinuous at $x=0$, and this is wrong. And that the correct formulation is $f(x)=1/x$ is continuous $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

It really depends on the precise definition of "discontinuous".

Sometimes there is a subtle difference between **discontinuous** and "not continuous". I've seen some sources where "discontinuous" means "defined, but not continuous"; whereas "not continuous" means "either not defined, or defined but not continuous". If this is the case, then "$\frac{1}{x}$ is discontinuous at $0$" would be *false*, but it would *not* be the same as "$\frac{1}{x}$ is not continuous at $0$". That is, under those conventions,

> $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $a$.

is *not* synonymous with

> $f(x)$ is not continuous at $a$.

Comment: Right: this is related to the comments I made to The Chaz's answer.

Comment: @Pete: Quite so. What I wanted to highlight is that VVV used one turn of phrase in the comments, and the other in the question, as if they were identical. It's entirely possible the two phrases are not synonymous (and I've certainly seen sources where they are *not* synonymous).

Answer (score 4):

Probably more egregiously, is that you can't hope to extend the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ on $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ to a (right, left) continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ because neither of the limits $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0^\pm}f(x)$ exist.

Answer (score 4):

I guess by continuous you mean 'continuous function'.

Then to define a function you need to specify a domain and codomain. But $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}: f(x)=1/x$ is not a function, since it is not well defined at $x=0$.

If you specify, for example $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}: f(x)=1/x$, then this is well-defined (and continuous)

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to extend $f(x) = 1/x$ to a continuous function on all of $\mathbb{R}$ because $\lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x) = -\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = +\infty$

---

*(Leftover from before)*

$x = 0$ is not in the domain of the function, so it is not clear what it would mean for $f$ to be discontinuous there.

<s>Also, the left- and right-sided limits are $- \infty$ and $+ \infty$, respectively, and this would poses even *more* problems even if you had your function defined on (say) all of $\mathbb{R}$.</s>

Comment: Now, if we consider $f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$, we *still* have that $x = 0$ is outside our domain, but (springing off of Mark Bennet's comment) this is a *removable singularity*. In other words, if we (which we can) define $f(0) = 1$, then we will have a continuous function everywhere (including at $x = 0$).

Comment: This is incorrect. You can't talk about a real-valued function $f:S\subseteq\mathbf{R}\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$ being discontinuous at a point outside of $S$. It would be correct to say that the function $f:\mathbf{R}\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$ defined by $f(x)=1/x$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=2$ is discontinuous at zero.

Comment: I agree with Keenan.  There is no such thing as a "maximal domain" for a function, so are we supposed to say that every function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ between topological spaces is discontinuous at all the points at which it is not defined?  E.g. that every function I have ever seen written down is discontinuous at me (i.e., at the "point" Pete L. Clark)?  This seems like an unnecessarily weird position to take...

Comment: @Pete: Can you please elaborate on the "maximal domain" discussion? It's as if you've detected - and named! - a misconception that I have. And then to correct my claim, would we define $f(0)$ and then show that no real value makes f continuous at 0? Could we add the point at infinity and claim that it **is** continuous?

Comment: @Chaz: What I'm saying is that the idea that a function is "discontinuous" at all points which are not in its domain looks weird when you move beyond functions having as their domain some subset of the real numbers.  It's still just terminology: the really mathematical issue here is the following: suppose you have a topological space $X$, a subspace $Y$ and a continuous function $f: Y \rightarrow Z$.  Now let $x \in X$.  The question is whether $f$ can be **continuously extended** to $Y \cup \{x\}$.  (This is only interesting if $x \in \overline{Y}$.) ...

Comment: In the example of $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ as a function from $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, as I'm sure you know, no such continuous extension to $x = 0$ is possible, in this case because $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: @Pete: How does one "strike through" text in an answer? I'd like to amend this answer.

Comment: `<s>Like this</s>`.